# How to customize ASP.NET MVC SiteMap to behave like menu with submenus

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvcsitemapprovider

Is there any way to add css to ASP.NET MVC SiteMap to make it behave something like this one: http://tdanryan.com/mvccontrib/

Basically i need to generate menu with css classes or ids, but i could not see how could i pass css classes names or menu id as params to menu.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu()
```

Helpful tutorial
http://edspencer.me.uk/2011/09/20/mvc-sitemap-provider-tutorial-2-breadcrumbs/